# how to attach a callback to Bootstrap Typeahead plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Using the custom bootstrap plugin for typeahead functionality
https://gist.github.com/1891669

How to attach a callback for 'select' event?
The following code doesn't work.

```
var selectedFn = $('.typeahead dropdown-menu').on('select', function( ev ){
    console.log(ev);
});
```

Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 13):

A new way of doing this is:

```
$('.input').typeahead({ 
    // snip
}).on('typeahead:selected', function() {
    // on selected
});
```

Comment: This is great, +1 because this worked for me. Could you explain why this documentation says its typeahead:select when its really typeahead:selected? https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events

Comment: nope, this was correct back it '13, maybe the api changed in the dev version?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myselector').typeahead({
itemSelected:function(data,value,text){
   console.log(data)
    alert('value is'+value);
    alert('text is'+text);
},
//your other stuffs
});
```

You have to just pass itemSelected in the callback function and it will give you the selected item.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just listen to your inputs change event like this:

`$('input.typeahead').on('change', function () { ... })`

Comment: Inputs only fire the change event when the input loses focus.

Comment: This does however seem to be the only thing that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the arguments in the function that handles the event in order to get the value selected as suggested in the documentation at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events

```
.on('typeahead:select', function(ev,value) {
        //value = the selected object
        //e.g.: {State: "South Dakota", Capital: "Pierre"}
    })
```

It gives exactly the same result with typeahead:select instead of typeahead:selected. I'd rather go with the one which is documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.typeaheadGroupSelect').typeahead({ 
    // snip
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(data, value, text) {
    // on selected
    console.log(data);
    console.log(value.idPublic); // here you can access all json object by using value.key
    console.log(value.name);
});
```

I used above code snippet to access data from the selection and assign certain hidden values to another input.

Prior I added an object to the data source typeahead is using to query data, see below:

```
var jsonData = [
        {"id":"1","idPublic":"978343HFJ","name":"Volkswagen Group Sales International"},
        {"id":"2","idPublic":"8343JJR98","name":"BMW Group Sales APAC"},
        {"id":"3","idPublic":"935723JFF","name":"Jaguar Group Sales Asia"},
        {"id":"4","idPublic":"3243JFUFF","name":"Mercedes Benz Group Sales Europe"}
    ];
```